# Any way to make Firefox only reload localhost resources?

Tags: firefox, localhost, cdn, developer-tools

I'm developing a website and use Firefox. Unfortunately my internet connection is very slow, and when I refresh the page (to see my changes) it of course also forces the browser to reload any remote resources (things loaded from CDNs for example).

Is there a way to make Firefox reload only what's coming from my localhost web server, and use the cached version for any remote resources like it does when browsing normally?

Answer (score 0):

Download the files referred from to local and refer in your page during development.

Comment: Well... that's kind of what I didn't want to do 